# Getting "Can only concatenate str (not "int") to str" when adding to a value read from a file

Tags: python, file-read

I would like the bots.txt to be read as an **int** instead of an **str**. However none of the  videos i find on the internet help, or go into major detail on how I can solve this issue.

Here is my code

```
import time
import os
import random
os.system('mode 88,30')
with open('B://JakraG2//.Bots//bots.txt', 'r') as f:
    aaa = f.read()
counter = aaa
    while True:
    time.sleep(0.05)
    print("Added 1 to bots.txt")
    counter = counter + 1
    lel = "{}".format(counter)
    with open('B://JakraG2//.Bots//bots.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write("{}".format(lel))
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loader.py", line 16, in <module>
    counter = counter + 1
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

bots.txt

```
0
```

Comment: IndentationError .... also:   `counter = int(aaa)` and `f.write(f"{counter+1}")` (get rid of the counter increments and the other interactions with lel etc

Comment: Try converting to int: `counter = int(aaa)`

Comment: If you are sure that text file contains only an integer you can cast it to int before adding 1. `counter=int(counter)+1`

Comment: @LouisCloete When I try that, it gives me this: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Then you need to add your file you are reading as a code block in your question so we can see its format.

Comment: Please include a sample of the input file `bots.txt`. This will help clarify your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read from a file with f.read, the information acquired is determined as a string, which is why when you try to add 1 to counter ( f.e  5 + 1), the program thinks you are trying to do something like this "5" + 1.

A simple fix would be to state that what you read from the file is an integer:

```
aaa = int(float(f.read()))
```

Comment: aaa = int(f.read())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Would you mind adding to the question the file you are reading? That way we can see the format of its content. However, try with aaa = int(float(f.read())), it might solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

File when read are always strings - you need to convert to integer to use integer addition.

```
import time

# read file 
try:
    with open('bots.txt', 'r') as f:       # you use B://JakraG2//.Bots//bots.txt'
        aaa = f.read().strip()
        counter = int(aaa)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)   # for informational purposes when testing
    counter = 0  # f.e. file not exists or invalid text2number in it

while True:
    time.sleep(0.05)
    print("Added 1 to bots.txt")
    counter = counter + 1
    
    # overwrites existing file
    with open('bots.txt', 'w') as f:       # you use B://JakraG2//.Bots//bots.txt'

        f.write(f"{counter}")
```

Comment: @kevlar if you get an IndentationError with this code you copy/pasted something wrong. The code works as is.